# Convert dataframe to hash-map using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My data-frame looks like:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
|        Nationality|    continent|
+-------------------+-------------+
|       Turkmenistan|         Asia|
|         Azerbaijan|         Asia|
|             Canada|North America|
|         Luxembourg|       Europe|
|             Gambia|       Africa|
```

My output should look like this:

```
Map(Gibraltar -> Europe, Haiti -> North America)
```

So, I'm trying to convert the data-frame into

```
scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
```

I'm trying with following code:

```
    var encoder = Encoders.product[(String, String)]
    val countryToContinent = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
    var mapped = nationalityDF.mapPartitions((it) => {
        ....
        ....
        countryToContinent.toIterator
    })(encoder).toDF("Nationality", "continent").as[(String, String)](encoder)

    val map = mapped.rdd.groupByKey.collect.toMap
```

But the result map has following output:

```
Map(Gibraltar -> CompactBuffer(Europe), Haiti -> CompactBuffer(North America))
```

How I can get the hash-map result without CompactBuffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create some data:

```
val df = Seq(
("Turkmenistan", "Asia"), 
("Azerbaijan", "Asia"))
.toDF("Country", "Continent")
```

Try to map into a tuple first then collect into a map:

```
df.map{ r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1))}.collect.toMap
```

Output:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Turkmenistan -> Asia, Azerbaijan -> Asia)
```

Comment: Thank you. its working fine .. I just added encoder to the map::
 newDF.map{ r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1))}(encoder).collect.toMap

Comment: Hello @Hanan why did you add the encoder explicitly? In this case I don't think you need to set the encoder. I would avoid to mess with encoders unless it is necessary :)  ie Spark can't recognize the encoding of my custom type! here you can find a nice explanation about the encoders https://github.com/vaquarkhan/Apache-Kafka-poc-and-notes/wiki/Apache-Spark-custom-Encoder-example

Comment: Actually it gave error before I added the encoder: Error:(58, 34) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[(String, String)])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, String)].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.
  countryToContinent = newDF.map { r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1)) }.collect.toMap

Comment: right I see you should completely remove the encoder then! You dont really need it. Just import spark.implicits._ shoud be enough

Comment: Thanks much! yes you're wright ... it works fine using spark.implicits._